# How to map a complex model that is the base for other models in Dart

Tags: dart, oop, generics

I have a model that I want to take the response from an HTTP request and map it. The problem is that this model has a property that takes in any property, but I want to map it correctly.

```
class BaseResponse<T> {
  final bool error;
  final String? message;
  final T? result;

  const BaseResponse({required this.error, this.message, this.result});

  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    bool error = json['error'];
    String? message = json['message'];
    T? result = json['result'];

    return BaseResponse(error: error, message: message, result: result);
  }
}
```

I would like to figure out a way that I can map in the correct data from the JSON for the result property. The result property can be a complex model, or something simple as a `String`.

```
class SampleModel {
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final AddressModel address;

    SampleModel({ required this.firstName, required this.lastName, required this.address });
}

class AddressModel {
    final String street;
    final String city;
    // ... more properties

    AddressModel({ required this.street, required this.city, /* More properties here */ });
}

void main() {
    Future<void> getResponse() async {
        Future<http.Response> response = await http.get('https://getsomething.com');

        // Do some checks against response

        BaseResponse<SampleModel> = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }

    getResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that you want a `BaseResponse<SampleModel>`, and there is something specific you need to do for the `SampleModel`, then you must call code which knows what to do, or tell that code what to do.

What I would do is to add a function parameter to `SampleModel.fromJson` which converts the `json[result]` to the desired type, then pass a decoder for the desired result type to it:

```dart
  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, 
      T? Function(Object?) parseResult) {
    bool error = json['error'];
    String? message = json['message'];
    T? result = parseResult(json['result']);
    return BaseResponse(error: error, message: message, result: result);
  }
```

Let `SampleModel` declare a decoder:

```
static SampleModel fromJson(Object? result) {
  if (result case {
      "firstName": String first,  
      "lastName": String last,
      "address": Map<String, Object?> addressJson,
      // ..
    }) {
      var address = AddressModel.fromJson(addressJson);
      if (address != null) {
        return SampleModel(firstName: first, lastName: last, address: address);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and pass that function along when you call `fromJson`:

```dart
      // Do some checks against response
      BaseResponse<SampleModel> model = BaseResponse.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>,
          SampleModel.fromJson); // <-- added here.
```

The `BaseResponse` is parameterized by a type. Inside the `BaseResponse` class, a generic type parameter should be treated *generically*. That is, it the code should not depend on the type actually bound to `T`, it should work the same for any type.

That does mean that any *type-specific* behavior must be provided from outside of the `BaseResponse` class.
Dart doesn't allow calling static functions through a type parameter,
so any functionality that needs a different behavior for each actual type argument, needs to be passed into the class. Either when it's needed or in a constructor.

Another way to cut the abstraction could be pass in the result *value*,
and call the `BaseResponse.fromJson` from another helper function:

```dart
class BaseResponse<T extends Object> {
  ...
  BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, T? result) :
    this(error: json['error'], message: json['message'], result: result);
}

class SampleModel {
  static SampleModel? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // Parse firstName/lastName/etc as above.
    return sample;
  }

  static BaseResponse<SampleModel> baseFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    SampleModel? result = fromJson(json);
    return BaseResponse<SampleModel>(json, result);
  }
}
```

Then this will be called by code like:

```dart
  // Do some checks against response.
  BaseResponse<SampleModel> model = SampleModel.baseFromJson(json);
```

This also chooses a code path that does something specific for the `SampleModel` that the checks have said to use, and uses the generic
code of `BaseResponse` with inputs that depend on the generic type.
It just passes a value instead of a function-to-create-a-value.

Either can work.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart "only objects of type int, double, String, bool, null, List, or Map (with string keys) are directly encodable into JSON. List and Map objects are encoded recursively" see [dart:convert](https://dart.dev/libraries/dart-convert).

As it stands your program will only work with those primitive types (see terminal output below). As **lrn** stated above you will have to instruct your program how to decode specific types.

Here is a code sample that can be copy/pasted and tried out in a [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev).

```
class AddressModel {
  final String street;
  final String city;
  // ... more properties
  AddressModel({
    required this.street,
    required this.city,
    /* More properties here */
  });
  factory AddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AddressModel(street: json['street'], city: json['city']);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$runtimeType(street: $street, city: $city)';
  }
}

class SampleModel {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final AddressModel address;
  SampleModel(
      {required this.firstName, required this.lastName, required this.address});

  factory SampleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SampleModel(
        firstName: json['firstName'],
        lastName: json['lastName'],
        address: AddressModel.fromJson(json['address']));
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$runtimeType(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, address: $address)';
  }
}

typedef JsonDecoder<T> = T? Function(Map<String, dynamic> json);

class BaseResponse<T> {
  final bool error;
  final String? message;
  final T? result;

  const BaseResponse({required this.error, this.message, this.result});
  
  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, {JsonDecoder<T>? jsonDecoder}) {
    bool error = json['error'];
    String? message = json['message'];
 
    return (jsonDecoder == null)? BaseResponse(
            error: error, message: message, result: json['result'] as T?): 
    BaseResponse(
            error: error, message: message, result: jsonDecoder(json['result']));
   }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$runtimeType(result: $result)';
  }
}

void main() {
  final jsonString = {'error': false, 'message': 'Hello', 'result': 'A simple String.'};
  final jsonListOfString = {'error': false, 'message': 'Hello', 'result': ['A simple String.']};
  final jsonAddress = {
    'error': false,
    'message': 'Hello',
    'result': {'city': 'Oslo', 'street': 'Anderson'}
  };
  final jsonSampleModel = {
    'error': false,
    'message': 'Hello',
    'result': {
      'firstName': 'Johan',
      'lastName': 'Andersen',
      'address': {'city': 'Oslo', 'street': 'Dass Gate'}
    }
  };
  final BaseResponse<String> r0 = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonString);
  final BaseResponse<List<String>> r1 = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonListOfString);
  final BaseResponse<AddressModel> r2 = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonAddress, jsonDecoder: (json) => AddressModel.fromJson(json));
  final BaseResponse<SampleModel> r3 = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonSampleModel, jsonDecoder: (json) => SampleModel.fromJson(json));

  print(r0);
  print(r1);
  print(r2);
  print(r3);
}
```

And the terminal output generated by running `main`:

```
BaseResponse<String>(result: A simple String.)
BaseResponse<List<String>>(result: [A simple String.])
BaseResponse<AddressModel>(result: AddressModel(street: Anderson, city: Oslo))
BaseResponse<SampleModel>(result: SampleModel(firstName: Johan, lastName: Andersen, address: AddressModel(street: Dass Gate, city: Oslo)))
```

As a side note: [Dart patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns#validating-incoming-json) are a powerful tool when it comes to validating incoming json.